# ~/.bashrc path for RSpec on Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rspec

I installed RSpec on Lion (10.7.4) using sudo gem install rspec but I keep getting "-bash: spec: command not found" when I try "spec".

I think it is because of the path, so I guess I need to update ~/.bashrc , but I have no idea how. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The name of the command line script is `rspec`, not `spec`.

Comment: was following this tutorial: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2007/05/14/an-introduction-to-rspec-part-i/ and it says "The spec command gets installed when you install the rspec gem.", so am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That article was written in 2007. The name of the command has changed since then.